# Who accepted/rejected the task?

Tags: 2013, workflow, tasks

I have a workflow which is creating a task that can be approved by multiple users. (IE: there is a group in the "Assigned To" field). How can I tell, from within the workflow, which user accepted/rejected the task? I can look at the "last modified by" field but it's not a very nice solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You delve into the task and in the "When the Task Process completes" step, you can identify the user who is modifying the Task at the time - i.e. Current Item: Modified By (if using SPD)

Comment: Workflows are not instant but dependent on a timer job AFAIK. So, what happens if a task gets approved by person A, and one minute later, person B opens the task and changes the date? The workflow timer job will execute maybe 3 minutes later, and find person B modified the task last and think that he was the one who approved. Not sure if I agree with using "Modified By"...

Comment: They are still sequential in terms of processing. the modified by ensures that the person who made the current change is captured. When person B opens the task, it'll already be set Approved or Rejected and hte task is considered closed. unless you also require multiple authorisations, so in that case, capture all of the task editors in the same way.